# Ffmpeg with forced ismv

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

I'm using ffmpeg to encode some live channels which will be delivered after by Unified Streaming. My player is a STB that is having issues reproducing this output, but on iOS works like charm.

When having an http output, it requires:

```
-moveflag isml -f ismv
```

If the output is an ismv file, I eliminate those flags and create the manifest with mp4split and my STB reproduces it.

This doesn't work on my STB:

```
ffmpeg -nostdin -loglevel info -y -re -i udp://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX?pkt_size=1316\&buffer_size=409600\&fifo_size=1000000\&overrun_nonfatal=1 -c:v libx264 -preset medium -profile:v baseline -g 50 -keyint_min 50 -sc_threshold 0 -c:a libfdk_aac -ac 2 -b:a 64k -map 0:v -b:v:0 1200k -minrate 1200k -maxrate 1200k -bufsize 2400k -muxrate 2400k -s:v:0 1280x720 -x264opts pic-struct:no-scenecut -movflags isml+frag_keyframe -f ismv -threads 0 -map 0:a http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/Teledoce_HD/Teledoce_HD.isml/Streams(video)
```

After creating the manifest with mp4split, this work on my STB:

```
ffmpeg -nostdin -loglevel info -y -re -i udp://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX?pkt_size=1316\&buffer_size=409600\&fifo_size=1000000\&overrun_nonfatal=1 -c:v libx264 -preset medium -profile:v baseline -g 50 -keyint_min 50 -sc_threshold 0 -c:a libfdk_aac -ac 2 -b:a 64k -map 0:v -b:v:0 1200k -minrate 1200k -maxrate 1200k -bufsize 2400k -muxrate 2400k -s:v:0 1280x720 -x264opts pic-struct:no-scenecut -movflags frag_keyframe -threads 0 -map 0:a test.ismv
```

I believe is something with the length of the stream, that my player on live streams can't know, but with vod yes.

Any idea?